# PyQt4 plugin in c++ application

Tags: c++, python

How is it posible to load python script as plugin in qt based application?

The basic idea would be to make a class in c++

`class b
{
    virtual void method1();
    virtual void method2();
}`

and 'somehow' inherit it in python like

`class c(b):
    def method1:
        #do something
    def method2:
        #do something`

I need to be able to modify the gui from python( add buttons to some widgets made in c++ with qt ). Basicaly something similiar to (gedit, blender, etc) plugin architecture with qt

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll first need to expose your C++ methods using [Python C API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/index.html) or by using [Boost::Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) or [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) and then [embed](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) Python into your application in order to execute customized Python scripts.